# git diff of current version with branching commit

Tags: git, branch, diff

I have to review code done by someone else in his own branch. He branched weeks ago from our main branch.

Since then, both branches have diverged, and I need to identify which changes he made.

How can I identify the "branching commit" (the commit that he branched from) and diff his current version VS that commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to identify the branching commit is to use merge-base:

```
git merge-base main-branch other-branch
```

But git provides some other alternatives to do what you need.  If you want to see the changes introduced by your current branch, you can use this syntax:

```
git diff main-branch...HEAD
```

This syntax will compute the merge-base between `main-branch` and `HEAD`, and then show you all the changes introduced by `HEAD`.  If your not currently on the branch you want to examine, you can just replace `HEAD` with the name of the branch:

```
git diff main-branch...other-branch
```

ProGit has a [description of this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#Determining-What-Is-Introduced) as well.

To see the changes introduced by a branch with `git log`, you want to use the two dot notation (`..`):

```
git log main-branch..HEAD
```

That will show you the commits introduced by the current branch that are not on the main branch.

The `...` notation with git log will show you all commits introduced on either branch since the merge-base, which is not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

The information is trivially available: the "branching" commit is the last common ancestor of the "review" commit and the "main" commits.

Tools like **gitk** can show you this sort of information graphically; you can easily copy commit hashes out of them for use with commandline tools.